# 404 on Default/Home page of Dnn 9.0.2 site

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I've installed Dnn 9.0.2 on my local dev machine, everything installed just fine.

For some reason I get a 404 for the default page '/'.

I've checked the Site Settings to make sure the Home Page is correctly selected, which it is.

I don't see any kind of strange redirects happening in Firebug.

Any other reasons why this might happen?

**Edit:**

I changed the Site Settings > Home Page to any other random page and logged out. It worked, no 404. Changed it back to Home, 404 returns.
The URL value for each page Home and RandomPage changes to '/' when set to be the home page, but it works for RandomPage and not for Home.

Comment: Did you do an upgrade or fresh install. I just did a fresh one and I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: @VDWWD it was a fresh install. I just created another page called Home 2, went to site settings and selected it as the Home page, deleted the old Home page then renamed Home 2 to Home and it fixed the problem. It solved my problem, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up creating a new page called Home 2 then deleting the original Home page (from the recycle bin as well), renaming Home 2 to Home and then using the new page in Site Settings.

I couldn't find any reason why this might happen.